# WorkBenchPage.hideView disposes the IViewPart in Eclipse Luna.

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I have created some View parts for my application using Eclipse Indigo. Then I have updated my sources to Eclipse Luna where the View parts get disposed whenever I do hide the View parts by calling hideView() of IWorkBenchPage. It gets created newly again when I call showView() of IWorkBenchPage. While in Indigo this is not the case that the view parts doesn't get disposed when the hideView() is called.

So how to hide a View part from workbenchpage without disposing it?

Comment: hideView has always disposed the view if it is not open in another perspective (for example see bug [105034](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=105034) where someone was complaining this did not work).

Comment: I understood. I am not opening the views in more than one perspective in case of Indigo also. In indigo, the views are not getting disposed on hideView() call. I don't understand why i am not getting the same behavior with Eclipse Luna.

Comment: Thanks greg. I understood the reason why i got that issue in my application.